# "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file" when trying to write to file

Tags: python, io

I'm trying to modify a csv file but keep getting the error:

```
 modifiedFile.write(new)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

The code I did is:

```
originalFileName = 'C:/Users/Janedoe/Desktop/My Projects/tickerinfo.csv'
modifiedFileName = 'C:/Users/Janedoe/Desktop/My Projects/tickerInfoWithDelta.csv'

def calculateDelta(o, c):
    oInt = float(closingPrice)
    cInt = float(openingPrice)
    calculatedDelta = (oInt-cInt)
    return calculatedDelta

def direction():
    if calculatedDelta > 0 :
        direction = 1
    else:
        direction = 0
    return direction

with open(originalFileName, 'r', encoding = 'utf8') as originalFile, open(modifiedFileName, 'w', encoding = 'utf8') as modifiedFile:
    header = 'Date,Close,Open,Delta,Direction'
    line = originalFile.readline()
    line = originalFile.readline()
while line != '':
    lineList = line.split(',')
    date = lineList[1]
    closingPrice = lineList[2]
    openingPrice = lineList[5]
    delta = calculateDelta(openingPrice, closingPrice)
    new = str(date) + ',' + str(closingPrice) + ',' + str(openingPrice) + ',' + str(delta) + ',' + str(direction) + '\n'
    modifiedFile.write(new)
```

When I open the modified file, it is blank. It's for a beginner's python course, so that being said my knowledge is limited and anything helps!

Comment: Suggestion: you should have tried to search for the error message you're getting, e.g. "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file."

Comment: Your title should only describe the specific issue you face (*"ValueError: I/O operation on closed file. when trying to write to file"*), not your entire use-case.

Comment: Also, to reproduce this we don't need your functions `calculateDelta()`, `direction()`, we only need some of the lines from `with` statement onwards, redact all the irrelevant lines. Examples on SO are required to be [mcve].

Comment: Maybe your issue is caused by bad indenting the `while`-loop; the `with` statement will automatically close its file object as soon as it goes out-of-scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`modifiedFile` is "opened" on the `with open` line. After that indentation context ends, the file is closed.

You can't write to a closed file.

One thing you can do is move the writes under that `with open` context (indentation).